# Boustrophedon-like writing system with single character orientation

Tags: written-language, writing-systems

Did a writing system ever develop that had a bi-directional writing style, alternating every line, with character orientation and order being preserved between lines? (Essentially Boustrophedon, without changing the orientation or word order of letters each line)

A hypothetical example of this writing system, would be the following:

"The quick brown fox

".dog lazy the over jumps

(Reading L-R in Ln 1, then R-L in Ln 2)

Comment: Can you give an example of "one character orientation"?

Comment: So for example:
"The quick brown fox (br)
jumps over the lazy dog"

Versus the hypothetical style I proposed:
"The quick brown fox (br)
dog lazy the over jumps"
So there aren't two different orientations per character (LR & RL) but just one (LR). (br - line break)

Comment: So you actually mean the character order within a word, not orientation of individual characters (L vs. ⅃)?

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/504/39

Comment: @VladimirF I've edited the question to further specify that character order also remains preserved, in addition to orientation.

Comment: @AlexB. Can you point out which of the examples would be like the one asked here?

Comment: @VladimirF  if it is about boustrophedon with character order remaining preserved, then the answer is "not attested." The reason why I included the link was to show what has been attested and described in professional research. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a quite high level "no" answer. All boustrophedon like writing systems I have ever seen in practice are of two types:

- (standard) boustrophedon, where the direction of the current line is hinted by the direction of the glyphs (in hieroglyphic writing, all persons and animals look in the writing direction, in alphabetic scripts the asymmetric glyphs also hint the direction.
- reverse boustrophedon, like Rongorongo, where the glyphs are also turned over, so in effect the glyphs are rotated 180 degree.

When the writing system is alphabetic or syllabic (with multisyllabic words), the order of letters or syllables is in general "as they are heard/read".

Everything beyond that is reaching into the realm of weak cryptography (permutation codes).

I have several books on writing systems of the world (e.g. Jensen: Die Schrift; Haarmann: Universalgeschichte der Schrift) and none of them mentions any boustrophedon-like writing system where the glyphs don't adapt to the current reading/writing direction.